# jQuery "slideDown" animation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this little script which is supposed to:

1) slideUp the element with class="text"

2) Change the inner content with "This is the new text"

3) slideDown the hidden text.

```
var newText = "This is the new text";
$(".text").slideUp("400").queue(function(){
    $(this).html(newText);
}).queue(function(){
    $(this).slideDown("400");
});
```

But the third step is misteriously not working. I can see through DOM inspector the 2 step worked and the content actually changed. But the ".text" element remains with style="display:none;".

I don't know what is wrong, there are no errors. Why is this (not) happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for you to use `.queue()` here.

Use the callback functions provided by jQuery's animation methods like [`.slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/):

```
var newText = "This is the new text";
$(".text").slideUp(400, function(){
    $(this).html(newText).slideDown(400);
});
```

If you really must use `.queue()` you can do. But you don't queue after changing the `.html()` as it isn't a queued method. You just need to `.dequeue()` and *then* call `.slideDown()`:

```
var newText = "This is the new text";
$(".text").slideUp("400").queue(function(){
    $(this).html(newText).dequeue().slideDown(400);
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cwnh4z76/1/)

Comment: Many thanks, I have forgotten to use the dequeue(). By the way I'm using your first solution which is simpler. I feel really stupid for not having thought about the callback function :D

Answer (score 1):

See http://jsfiddle.net/rhg94f5b/

You don't need to queue animations, just call one after the other. You can change the text on the complete callback of the first slide and then slide down:

```
$(".text").slideUp("400", function() {
    $(this).html(newText);
}).slideDown("400");
```